# Community URL - Add Object ID

Tags: community

I have a **public** community (experience cloud) URL which is like:
...force.com/MyCommunityName/s/
Inside it, I have only a lightning component (which contains everything for the page).

I wonder if it would be possible to do like this (or something similar):
...force.com/MyCommunityName/s/0015r00000IhCERAA3

So that I could reference this Id on the Lightning component logic.

Does anyone know if is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Digital Experiences do not support URL addressable components (you find this documented [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:isUrlAddressable/documentation)). You have to create a page in the site (with defined URL), drop the component on the page (ensure that your component has an API property, such as `recordId` that accepts the ID) and populate this property in the component properties in the experience page using an expression (this is all done through the Experience Builder).

If you define the URL to include a named parameter binding, like `/my-url/:recordId`, then the expression just needs to be of the form "{!recordId}". I.e. the binding name (after the colon in the URL) is used.

On the other hand, if you have the URL accept a query parameter, such that the page URL at runtime is like `.../my-url?id=00axxxxxx`, then the expression is of the form "{!id}". I.e. the query parameter name is used.